# div & iframe beside each other in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html, autoresize

i am having a div containing the menu aligned lef and an iframe which aligned right, also a button which slideToggle to show/hide the div, what i wanna do is to make the iframe resize it self automatically when the div disappears to take the whole width of the page, and give space to the div when it appears, how i can achieve that?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".mmenu").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
 <button class="flip">Show.Hide menu</button>
                     <div id="nav" class="mmenu" style="float: left; border-radius: 10px; position: fixed;
                             bottom: 75px;border: 5px solid #003366; bottom: 50px;">
                            <ul type="none">
                                <li><a target="collabsoft" href= "ProfilePage.php?property_variable=mine">My Profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="collabsoft" href= "viewMessages.php">Messages</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="collabsoft" href= "userHomepage.php">My Conferences</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <iframe scrolling="no" id="collabsoft" name="collabsoft" src="latestNews.php" style="position: relative;
                             width: 950px; height: 100%;></iframe>
```

Comment: Why are you using an iframe? This can affect the solution.

Comment: @Blowski i have to use iframe to load content of the website inside it.

Comment: why is the content not loaded into the page directly, instead of in an iframe? iframes have all sorts of problems, and you should use them as a last resort.

Comment: you have a fixed width on iframe (950px) so changing width will no happen, you need to close " on that iframe too, plus the button is at left of the iframe, it occupies space too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same solution as `@Pakauji Pakau`, but for a slightly simpler case: http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/x6djM/1/.

Since there's different stuff going on on show and hide, I'd use `show()` and `hide()` explicitly rather than `slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 1):

**you can try this, i have edited your code**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#nav").is(':visible')) {
            $("#iframe1").attr("width", "68%");
        }
        else {

            $("#iframe1").attr("width", "100%");

        }
        $(".flip").click(function () {
            if ($("#nav").is(':visible')) {
                $(".mmenu").slideToggle("slow");
                $("#iframe1").attr("width", "100%");
            }
            else {
                $(".mmenu").slideToggle("slow");
                $("#iframe1").attr("width", "68%");

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
<input type="button" class="flip" value="Show/Hide menu" />
<div>
    <div id="nav" class="mmenu" style="float: left; border-radius: 10px; border: 5px solid #003366;
        bottom: 50px;">
        <ul type="none">
            <li><a target="collabsoft" href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a target="collabsoft" href="#">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a target="collabsoft" href="#">My Conferences</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe1" scrolling="no" id="collabsoft" name="collabsoft" src="" style="height: 100%;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a possible solution. Or at least the beginning of one: http://jsfiddle.net/86Vgz/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a DIV to occupy the space at left and transfer the width of the menu on click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav").width($("#nav ul").outerWidth());
    $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".mmenu").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#nav").width($("#nav ul").outerWidth());
});
```

some more work above is needed to preserve animation

```
<body>
       <button class="flip">Show.Hide menu</button><br/>
   <div style="display:table;width:100%;border:solid 10px lime">
          <div id="nav" class="mmenu" style="display:table-cell">
             <ul type="none" style="border-radius: 10px; position: fixed; bottom: 75px;border: 5px solid #003366; bottom: 50px;">
                <li><a target="collabsoft" href= "ProfilePage.php?property_variable=mine">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a target="collabsoft" href= "viewMessages.php">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a target="collabsoft" href= "userHomepage.php">My Conferences</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div>
          <iframe scrolling="no" id="collabsoft" name="collabsoft" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;display:table-cell">XXX</iframe>
</div>
</body>
```